# How to test a `select(reselectSelector)` with jasmine?

Tags: reactjs, jasmine, redux-saga, reselect

I'm creating a [React](https://facebook.github.io/react/) application and use [react-boilerplate](https://github.com/react-boilerplate/react-boilerplate) as my base project. After getting my head around [Redux](https://github.com/reactjs/react-redux), [Sagas](https://github.com/redux-saga/redux-saga) and [reselect](https://github.com/reactjs/reselect) and got my first components running, I'd like to write the corresponding unit tests. But unfortunately I'm not able to get the test for the select statement with a corresponding selector to test correctly:

```
const selectDomain = () => (state) => state.get('myDomain');
const selectDomainMessage = () => createSelector(selectDomain(), (domain) => domain.get('message'));

function* send() {
  const message = yield select(selectDomainMessage());
  ...
  yield put(sentAction(message);
}

describe('send Saga', () => {
  const generator = send();

  it('should return select descriptor', () => {
    let expectedDescriptor = select(selectDomainMessage());
    let returnedDescriptor = generator.next().value;

    expect(returnedDescriptor).toEqual(expectedDescriptor);
  });
});
```

From my point of view, this test should work, but it fails with the (not really helpful) error message:

> Expected Object({ @@redux-saga/IO: true, SELECT: Object({ selector: Function, args: [  ] }) }) to equal Object({ @@redux-saga/IO: true, SELECT: Object({ selector: Function, args: [  ] }) }).

To easier reproduce the problem I created a [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/olivermue/qj9z0qkw/) with the needed environment. Maybe someone can tell me what I'm doing wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your test fails because the selector functions in the expected and actual cases are not referentially equivalent.

The function `selectDomainMessage` returns a function returned by `createSelector`; and each time `createSelector` runs, it returns a new function.

For your test to pass, you can capture the return function of `createSelector` as a variable and have `selectDomainMessage` return that:

```
const selector = createSelector(selectDomain(), (domain) => domain.get('message'))
const selectDomainMessage = () => selector;
```

Modified [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/1ovfjc3x/)